# How to show an image for image input field instead of default image input field?

Tags: html, css, forms, django-forms

I am trying to create a django form like the below image, when you upload the image, the uploaded image should be shown if the image is not uploaded the form should show the defult image.
[image: reference image]
please help, every suggestions might help.

If you could share a simple code snippet as an example, it would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.